# How to Generate Spool File in AS400?

Tags: ibm-midrange

I was doing the code change. After compiling the programs in RPG i want to do the testing. But when i run the command i am not able to get spool file for that run of command. Please help. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please tell us what's your problem. The RPG should generate a spool? Which name? Which printer?

Comment: What are you expecting to see in a spooled file? Generally, you'd have a program create a spooled file by having it open a printer file and then write records to it. But you seem to be asking about something different.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're correct and that the program creates a spool file...

Sounds like it's being sent to a printer automatically.  By default, once a spool file is printed it gets deleted from the system.

Try doing the following before running your program:

```
OVRPRTF FILE(MYPRTF) HOLD(*YES)
```

You'll need to use the name of the printer file used by your program in place of `MYPRTF`.  The `HOLD(*YES)` will prevent the spool file generated from the printer file from being sent to the assigned printer.

Comment: If the printer file is one created for this program, CHGPRTF MYPRTF HOLD(*YES) might be easier.  To use OVRPRTF will require a calling CL program.